# Cross Compiling python package for ARM

Tags: python, linux, arm, cross-compiling

How do i cross compile a python module for the ARM architecture? i have cross-compiled python as suggested by http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

i want to install python-crontab on my target imx6q board as there is no available crontab on the device. The device does not have ethernet. I want to execute a scheduled job using cron  for the board using python file. can somebody help me..? 
I have found something here ..
http://answers.ros.org/question/99066/install-python-module-for-cross-compile-target/
but i need something specific..